# Runkeeper Post request php

Tags: php, api, oauth

Currently working on a tool using the Runkeeper api but running (haha) into some issues regarding the post request I need to make in orde to fully authorize the thing.

I currently use this code:

```
  $grant_type ='authorization_code'; 
  $code = $codeR;
  $client_id = $this->client_id;
  $client_secret = $this->client_secret;
  $redirect_uri = $this->req_url; 

    $url = 'http://api.runkeeper.com';
    $data = array('grant_type' => $grant_type, 'code' => $code, 'client_id' => $client_id, 'client_secret' => $client_secret, 'redirect_url' => $redirect_uri);

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url,false,'',$options);

    return $result;
```

The codeR parameter is succesfully recieved after the user has been redirected to grand permission.

Anyone who can help?

Thanks!